# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jar

In my project I am calling the rest service using jersy client.Its working file in local.But not working in server.

In local i am using  `jdk1.7.0_10` 
In Server i am using `jdk1.7.0_80`

Local RunTime:  Tomcat
Server RunTime: `JBOSS`

```
Libraries:
jersey-bean-validation-2.22.jar
jersey-client-2.22.jar
jersey-common-2.22.jar
jersey-entity-filtering-2.22.jar
jersey-guava-2.7.jar
jersey-media-moxy-2.22.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar
jaxrpc.jar
```

Why its not working in server?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: any difference between the application server from local to server?

Comment: Your application probably embeds a JAX-RS dependency that your server also has, but with a different version. Then when the server starts, it favors its own dependency over the one supplied with your application.

Comment: only jdk version no other difference both are windows only @Roberto

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens, is there any way to tell the server that use the jar instead of its own dependency.

Comment: @Madhesh Yes, but of course the configuration depends on the server. But a better policy would be to just use the dependency provided by the application server since it's already there and change the code to adapt to that version of the library.

Comment: I don't think it gonna solve your problem, since the MultivaluedMap is part of the jdk and not of jersey.

Comment: @RobertoBenazzato MultivaluedMap is definitely not part of the JDK. It's part of the JAX-RS specification and Jersey is a reference implementation of that spec.

Comment: [https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html] wich differ from [https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/package-summary.html]

Comment: you are right..ok

Answer (score 1):

since you say in your comment

> But a better policy would be to just use the dependency provided by the application server since it's already there and change the code to adapt to that version of the library

You just need to use a method  subbported by both the interface definitions. (j2ee6 and j2ee7)

According with the official doorcale doc
[j2ee6](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/overview-summary.html) and
[j2ee7](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/overview-summary.html)
have the method add(K key, V value) in the interface definition. So instead of addAll you shuld use the metod Add to add each single entry

hope this help

Comment: Nothing wrong with using a newer version of an API, if you're sure you will deploy on an application server supporting it and you don't get version conflicts. It can happen easily when using Maven and not setting the proper scope (`provided`) for dependencies that are already supplied by the server.

Comment: I agree, but You need also to be carefull with application classloader wich haven't to be set on parent first, and, depeding on AS, you may experience some trouble of compatibility withthe endorsed lib.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` is thrown when a method is invoked that does not exist. This typically occurs when application code is developed with some version of an interface, while it is deployed in an environment with an older version of the interface that doesn't have certain methods of the newer version.

The class `MultivaluedMap` is part of the Java EE API (more specifically the JAX-RS API part of it). Check the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html

Notice how it states that the class has been available since version 1.0, meaning it was there since JAX-RS version 1.0.

The method `addAll` on the other hand, states it [has only been available since version 2.0](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap.html#addAll-K-java.util.List-)

This means your development has been done against version 2.0 of the API, but you're deploying on a server where implementation 1.0 is being used. Possible causes of this are:

- Your local environment has a newer version of the application server (maybe GlassFish?) than that of the server environment.
- The local environment had libraries added to the application server that aren't on the server environment.
- There's some other way in which the effective classpath of both environments differs, such as some dependencies that are deployed while testing locally but not in the final build, differences in environment variables etc.

Check which application server is used locally and on the server (GlassFish, Websphere, JBoss...), which versions are used on either environment and which JAX-RS API (and implementation) they bundle, and what gets bundled into your deployment archive (likely an EAR file).